# Does multiple struct (Nested structure) exist in C?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, declaration, member-access

I wonder if there is a way to declare multiple structs in C.
For example, I made this:

```
struct Team{
    char TeamName[20];
    int Point;
    int Goals;
};
typedef struct TeamCup {
    char GroupID;
    struct Team team;
}Group;
Group g1, g2;
```

I want each TeamCup to have 4 teams. But when it comes to input process, in my loop, the variable here is undefined:

```
g1.Team[i].Point;
```

Comment: If you want each `TeamCup` to have `4` `Team`, then you just have to write `struct Team team[4];` as always if you want an array. Then you only have a typo left: `g1.Team[i].Point;` -> `g1.team[i].Point;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want each TeamCup to have 4 teams

In this case you need to write

```
typedef struct TeamCup {
    char GroupID;
    struct Team team[4];
}Group;
```

and

```
g1.team[i].Point;
```

Thar is you need to declare an array of objects of the type `struct Team` within the structure `struct TeamCup`.